# How can I dynamically create a selector at runtime with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dynamic

I know how to create a `SEL` at compile time using `@selector(MyMethodName:)` but what I want to do is create a selector dynamically from an `NSString`. Is this even possible?

What I can do:

```
SEL selector = @selector(doWork:);
[myobj respondsToSelector:selector];
```

What I want to do: (pseudo code, this obviously doesn't work)

```
SEL selector = selectorFromString(@"doWork");
[myobj respondsToSelector:selector];
```

I've been searching the Apple API docs, but haven't found a way that doesn't rely on the compile-time `@selector(myTarget:)` syntax.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I'm not an Objective-C programmer, merely a sympathizer, but maybe [NSSelectorFromString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring?language=objc) is what you need. It's mentioned explicity in the [Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/chapter_9_section_3.html) that you can use it to convert a string to a selector.

Comment: I need to brush up on my Google-fu. that's exactly what I was (or wasn't as it may be) looking for.

Comment: Well, I still had the links flying around in my bookmarks since I've read through the Objective-C 2.0 docs a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 40):

According to the XCode documentation, your psuedocode basically gets it right.

> It’s most efficient to assign values to SEL variables at compile time with the @selector() directive. However, in some cases, a program may need to convert a character string to a selector at runtime. This can be done with the NSSelectorFromString function:

`setWidthHeight = NSSelectorFromString(aBuffer);`

Edit: Bummer, too slow. :P

Comment: `NSStringFromSelector(@"doWork")` converts it the other way (just fyi)

Comment: I think you mean, NSStringFromSelector(@selector(doWork))

Comment: And what does that selector supposedly do? Shouldn't we specify a block or something?

Answer (score 14):

I'd have to say that *it's a little more complicated* than the previous respondents' answers might suggest... if you indeed really want to **create a selector**... not just "call one" that you "have laying around"...

You need to create a function pointer that will be called by your "new" method..  so for a method like `[self theMethod:(id)methodArg];`, you'd write...

```
void (^impBlock)(id,id) = ^(id _self, id methodArg) { 
     [_self doSomethingWith:methodArg]; 
};
```

and then you need to  generate the `IMP` block dynamically, this time, passing, "self", the `SEL`, and any arguments...

```
void(*impFunct)(id, SEL, id) = (void*) imp_implementationWithBlock(impBlock);
```

and add it to your class, along with an accurate method signature for the whole sucker (in this case `"v@:@"`, void return, object caller, object argument)

```
 class_addMethod(self.class, @selector(theMethod:), (IMP)impFunct, "v@:@");
```

You can see some good examples of this kind of [*runtime shenanigans*, in one of my repos, here.](https://github.com/mralexgray/AtoZAutoBox)

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been answered for long ago, but still I wanna share. This can be done using `sel_registerName` too.

The example code in the question can be rewritten like this:

```
SEL selector = sel_registerName("doWork:");
[myobj respondsToSelector:selector];
```

Comment: Actually, ``NSSelectorFromString`` mentioned by @torsten-marek uses ``sel_registerName`` under the hood. [appledev](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring?language=objc): _"NSSelectorFromString passes a UTF-8 encoded character representation of aSelectorName to sel_registerName and returns the value returned by that function"_