# How do I express selector of OTHER classes in string?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I am in a `myClass.m`

I know I can do:

```
SEL aSelector = @selector(methodName);
```

I can latter do `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(Bookmark))`, for example.

Here, methodName is a selector for myClass.

Say I have a property named myProperty of type myPropertyClass and that class have a selector myPropertymethodname

How should I access it if say I want to express that selector using string.

Basically sometimes we want to use valueForKey rather than accessing the accessor directly. However, that's prone to mistyped. I want to use NSStringFromSelector instead

```
SEL aSelector = @selector(myPropertyClass.myPropertymethodname);
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: why can't you use `SEL aSelector = @selector(myPropertymethodname);`? a selector has no class concept in it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically create a selector at runtime with Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112643/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-selector-at-runtime-with-objective-c)

Comment: What? Really? How do you know? Wow.

Comment: can you turn that into an answer? But well, Justin have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the property's default named getter:

```
SEL aSelector = @selector(myPropertymethodname);
```

For the property's default named setter:

```
SEL aSelector = @selector(setMyPropertymethodname:);
                          ^^^^                   ^
```

Then just ensure the selector/property declaration is visible in the file you are compiling.

Note that a selector's name cannot be scoped-qualified to a specific class.