# Dynamically call a method from another class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I am trying to call a method from another class which is in another source file.

Example:

1. I have a file named `Source1.h/Source1.m` (both are objective C class files)
2. I have another file names `Source2.h/Source2.m` (both are objective C class files)
3. `Source1` contains 2 methods eg: `method1` and `method2`.
4. From `Source2` file, I need to call the `method1` from `source1` file.

I know how to do that in objective C. But in my `source2` file, the method names in `Source1` will be retrieved dynamically. I am not going to hard code it some thing similar to this.

```
Source1 *a = [[Source1 alloc]init];

[a method1];
```

The `method1` text will taken from a text file. I can use Selector to invoke a method from same class. But I can't use selector to call method from another class.

Please help to solve this issue....

Many Thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer seems to be relevant: [How can I dynamically create a selector at runtime with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112643/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-selector-at-runtime-with-objective-c)

Basically you can use NSSelectorFromString to make a selector from an UTF8 string in an NSString.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way :

MyClass contains the method called `myMethod` which is invoked from some other class.

```
MyClass *object=[MyClass new];

SEL mySelector=NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod"); //myMethod is a string, that you can read from any text file/source file and use it here.
```

//the following will create warning in ARC, you can suppress the warning by adding these

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [object performSelector:mySelector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Other way is to do by this:

```
#import <objc/message.h>//This is required to import
```

And then call the method by following code:

```
MyClass *object=[MyClass new]; 
SEL mySelector=NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod");
objc_msgSend(object,mySelector);
```